# QGIS 3 Madeira Move Point Features Button

Tags: gui, qgis-3

In QGIS 3 "Madeira" and "Bonn" I miss the button that allows you to move point features. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Johann B.! It's now under the **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar**. You will first need to select your points before you can move them (don't forget to enable _editing_).

Comment: You have this button in "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar"